# Typescript: index signature is missing in type when extending interface

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to do an extension of one of my interfaces, but keep getting the error "index signature is missing in type {dcs: Relationship} with the following snippet:

```
interface Relationship {
    data: {
        id: string;
        type: string;
    }
}

interface T {
    relationships: {[key: string]: Relationship};
}

interface Test extends T {
    relationships: {
        dcs: Relationship;
    };
}
```

The goal is for the relationships property in T to be an object with any number of keys that are all of the Relationship type. Test is supposed to be a specific implementation of type T.

Not sure what the correct way to approach this is. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `Test` like so:

```
interface Test extends T {
  relationships: {
    [key: string]: Relationship;
    dcs: Relationship;
  };
}
```

However, as you've noticed you end up having to declare the indexer again when you actually implement the interface. You could save some typing by doing this:

```
interface T {
  relationships: {
    [key: string]: Relationship;
  };
}

interface TestRelationships {
   [key: string]: Relationship;
   dcs: Relationship;
}

interface Test extends T {
  relationships: TestRelationships;
}

class T1 implements Test {
  relationships: TestRelationships;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I get the same issue though when I try and implement it in a class :/

`class T1 implements Test {
 relationships = {
  dcs: {
   data: {
    id: "test",
    type: "test"
   }
  }
 }
}`

Answer (score 1):

A solution too if the type **doesn't need to be an interface**! Is to use an **object literal type**

(( However adding the index signature to the interface can be a better option )) It's to show that we can do that too!

ex:

```js
export type SignalProcessorEvents =  {
    valueCandle: (
        value: WhalesCandle,
        storageType: StorageType | undefined
    ) => void
}
```

## Illustration:

When using the interface (typescript complaining)

[image]

When switching to object literal

[image]

Extension code for the one that want to see it:

```js
export class Events<EventsObject extends { [eventName: string]: (...args: any[]) => void}> {
    protected _events: EventsObject = {} as any;
```