# AssemblyScript compilation error: TS2329: Index signature is missing in type

Tags: typescript, assemblyscript, index-signature

I'm trying to create a sort function in AssemblyScript but am receiving this error in the function. I'd like the sort function to be re-usable and take in two possible sort parameters. I'm passing in a class that has an index signature but getting this error.

I've read several other questions that didn't help me solve it:

- [How to fix "Index signature is missing in type" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60697214/how-to-fix-index-signature-is-missing-in-type-error)
- [Typescript: index signature is missing in type when extending interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34959143/typescript-index-signature-is-missing-in-type-when-extending-interface)
- [How to declare one type for all class methods in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67862544/how-to-declare-one-type-for-all-class-methods-in-typescript)
- [Can I define a Typescript class which has an index signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977481/can-i-define-a-typescript-class-which-has-an-index-signature)

Also, came across this in their Github: https://github.com/AssemblyScript/assemblyscript/issues/1972

Full code here: https://pastebin.com/gXY5PxVn

Summary of code:

```js
export function processPlayers ( allPlayerData: Array<PlayerData> ): Array<PlayerData> {
    let players = sortPlayersByField(allPlayerData);
    ...
};

const sortPlayersByField = function(
    players: Array<PlayerData>,
    field: String = 'fantasy_points',
    secondaryField: String = ''
): Array<PlayerData>{
    const sortFunc = function(
        a: PlayerData,
        b: PlayerData
    ): i32{
        // --- Handle when the field isn't set or has no value
        if(!a[field] && !b[field]){
            return 0;
        }
        if(!a[field]){
            return 1;
        }
        if(!b[field]){
            return -1;
        }
        ...
    }
    players.sort(sortFunc)
    return players;
}

/**
 * Definition for all data for a player that gets returned by the query to get
 * all players in a league for the draft board
 */
class PlayerData {
    [key: String]: any // --- Index signature IS present
    player_id: number
    ...
}
```

Summary of the errors:

```
ERROR TS2329: Index signature is missing in type 'assembly/index/PlayerData'.
    :
 40 │ if(!a[field] && !b[field]){
    │     ~
    └─ in assembly/index.ts(40,13)

ERROR TS2329: Index signature is missing in type 'assembly/index/PlayerData'.
    :
 40 │ if(!a[field] && !b[field]){
    │                  ~
    └─ in assembly/index.ts(40,26)

ERROR TS2329: Index signature is missing in type 'assembly/index/PlayerData'.
    :
 43 │ if(!a[field]){
    │     ~
    └─ in assembly/index.ts(43,13)

ERROR TS2329: Index signature is missing in type 'assembly/index/PlayerData'.
    :
 46 │ if(!b[field]){
    │     ~
    └─ in assembly/index.ts(46,13)
```

I have tried to use an interface and assign it to the class but it results in the same error. I tried using a type like in some of the other questions I looked at but that didn't even work in AssemblyScript, it wouldn't compile while declaring a type. I've tried changing the signature of 'sortFunc' to not the PlayerData type but create a generic object type with the index signature included and that also results in compilation errors. Not sure how to handle this.

############################

**Second Example**

I ran into another example of this while trying to work around it. This one's a little more clear.

Full code here: https://pastebin.com/zKUCTLy4

```js
class DraftBoard {
    leagueFillNumbers: LeagueFillNumbers
    constructor(
        mvpBoardTeams: Array<MvpBoardTeam>
    ){
        this.leagueFillNumbers = new LeagueFillNumbers(mvpBoardTeams);
    }
}

class LeagueFillNumbers {
    [key: i32]: TeamFillNumbers
    constructor(
        mvpBoardTeams: Array<MvpBoardTeam>
    ){
        for(let i = 0; i < mvpBoardTeams.length; i++){
            this[mvpBoardTeams[i].id] = new TeamFillNumbers();
        }
    }
}

class TeamFillNumbers {
    [key: string]: i32
    constructor(){
        const fantasyPositions: Array<string> = PositionHelper.getFantasyPositionList();
        for(let i = 0; i < fantasyPositions.length; i++){
            this[fantasyPositions[i]] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler errors with:

```
ERROR TS2329: Index signature is missing in type 'assembly/index/LeagueFillNumbers'.
     :
 194 │ this[mvpBoardTeams[i].id] = new TeamFillNumbers();
     │ ~~~~
     └─ in assembly/index.ts(194,13)

ERROR TS2329: Index signature is missing in type 'assembly/index/LeagueFillNumbers'.
     :
 180 │ return this.leagueFillNumbers[mvpBoardTeamId];
     │        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     └─ in assembly/index.ts(180,16)
```

From what I understand, I've properly declared a key signature in all of these instances. I'm not sure what the issue is. I can discern that using the [] notation to set a dynamic property on an object is part of the issue since that is the only thing that's triggered it in both of my examples here.

Comment: I think you'll want to use type `string` rather than `String` throughout. [`string` is a type, `String` refers to the JS object type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727044/what-is-the-difference-between-types-string-and-string). In regular Typescript compilation this would get picked up earlier but perhaps AssemblyScript intercepts the error messages.

Comment: @motto thanks, I wasn't aware of that. I updated it. Also updated the question with another example I ran into.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while, but I have managed to *almost* solve it.

One of the problems seems to be that the class requires overloading the [`"[]"` operator](https://www.assemblyscript.org/editor.html#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) in order for the syntax `a[field]` to work. After trial and error, this seemed to work:

```js
@operator("[]")
foo(k: string): i32 {
  if (k == "player_id")                     {return this.player_id;}
  else if (k == "hasStats")                 {return this.hasStats;}
  else if (k == "rank")                     {return this.rank;}
  ...
```

Sadly, I could not get it to work with generic types, so I did it with only the numbers. I changed `number` to `i32`.

After this, another big problem was that AssemblyScript does not currently [support closures](https://www.assemblyscript.org/status.html#on-closures), which is what was happening with that custom sort function. So, in order to see if I can solve it, I refactored the code so that that function is standalone.

But because the `Array.sort()` method can only take 2 objects, and because you cannot pass the fields in this way without creating a closure, you have to sort it in the old fashioned way. I repurposed the typescript `quickSort` [code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort#TypeScript) from RosettaCode, I passed two additional parameters (`field` and `secondaryField`) and now it seems to work.

The only problem that remains is that I could not get the generics to work for that operator overloading, but maybe someone smarter than me can solve that part as well.

The code is [here](https://pastebin.com/Ee8CdivC). It is not complete, because I used the `console.log` function from javascript and I didn't include the `quickSort` implementation, but the idea is there.